# Generate a JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to generate a JSON file with python. But I can't figure out how to append each object correctly and write all of them at once to JSON file. Could you please help me solve this?  a, b, and values for x, y, z are calculated in the script.
Thank you so much

This is how the generated JSON file should look like

```
 {
  "a": {
    "x": 2,
    "y": 3,
    "z": 4
  },
  "b": {
    "x": 5,
    "y": 4,
    "z": 4
  }
}
```

This is python script

```
import json    
for i in range(1, 5):
    a = geta(i)
    x = getx(i)
    y = gety(i)
    z = getz(i)
    data = {
      a: {
        "x": x,
        "y": y,
        "z": z
      }}


 with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

Comment: This is too broad. Show what you have so far.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON to me. Are you sure you got the number of brackets right? You're basically doing `{1:2, 3}`.

Comment: @Kevin fixed JSON. Is it correct now?

Comment: If you already have dictionaries in Python that are structured the way you want, then putting them in a json file is easy: use the `json` module's `dump` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way will be to create whole dict at once:

```
data = {} 
for i in range(1, 5):
    name = getname(i)
    x = getx(i)
    y = gety(i)
    z = getz(i)
    data[name] = {
        "x": x,
        "y": y,
        "z": z
      }
```

And then save

```
 with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been struggling all day with this :)

Comment: @brabbit640 I'm glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use normal dictionaries in python when constructing the JSON then use the JSON package to export to JSON files.

You can construct them like this (long way):

```
a_dict = {}
a_dict['id'] = {}
a_dict['id']['a'] = {'properties' : {}}
a_dict['id']['a']['properties']['x'] = '9'
a_dict['id']['a']['properties']['y'] = '3'
a_dict['id']['a']['properties']['z'] = '17'
a_dict['id']['b'] = {'properties' : {}}
a_dict['id']['b']['properties']['x'] = '3'
a_dict['id']['b']['properties']['y'] = '2'
a_dict['id']['b']['properties']['z'] = '1'
```

or you can use a function:

```
def dict_construct(id, x, y, z):
 new_dic = {id : {'properties': {} } }
 values = [{'x': x}, {'y': y}, {'z':z}]
 for val in values:
    new_dic[id]['properties'].update(val)
 return new_dic

return_values = [('a', '9', '3', '17'), ('b', '3', '2', '1')]

a_dict = {'id': {} }
for xx in return_values:
    add_dict = dict_construct(*xx)
    a_dict['id'].update(add_dict)

print(a_dict)
```

both give you as a dictionary:

```
{'id': {'a': {'properties': {'x': '9', 'y': '3', 'z': '17'}}, 'b': {'properties': {'x': '3', 'y': '2', 'z': '1'}}}}
```

using json.dump:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(a_dict, outfile)
```

you get as a file:

```
{
  "id": {
    "a": {
      "properties": {
        "x": "9",
        "y": "3",
        "z": "17"
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "properties": {
        "x": "3",
        "y": "2",
        "z": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have a valid python dictionary (it seems like you already do)
2. I see you are trying to write your json in a file with

```
with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

You are opening data.json on "a" (append) mode, so you are adding your json to the end of the file, that will result on a bad json data.json contains any data already. Do this instead:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        # where data is your valid python dictionary
        json.dump(data, f)
```